# How to enable textbox in a particular row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i am trying to enable a textbox by clicking on the corresponding button but i click any button it always enables the first textbox , i dont want to use 'id' here

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("table tr").click(function() 
{
//alert( this.rowIndex );
$('#button1').prop('disabled', false);
 });
});

</script>
</head>
<table>
<tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" id="button1" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td>

</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

is there any method where i could use the `row index` function ?

Comment: Yes, because you are using id of that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without using an ID. The logic is to access the parent of the button and then its previous element and then find the text input element in it.

Working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=button]").click(function(){
    console.log("editing");
    $(this).parent().prev().find("input[type=text]").attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" id="button1" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td>

  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="test" disabled value="Edit"/> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit"/> </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use either the tag type or a class to identify your `input` elements in the row. Using an `id` for code you're trying to keep DRY is counter-intuitive.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="test" disabled="true" value="Edit" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Repeated HTML... -->
</table>
```

Then you can use the contextual selector to only find the `input` elements in the clicked `tr`:

```
$("table tr").click(function () {
    $('input', this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/55se8s3n/)

Comment: hey 1 sec .. this works but i want to use the edit button and not enable the textbox by clicking on the textbox itself

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $("table tr").click(function() 
   {
      //alert( this.rowIndex );
      $(this).find("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', false);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It enables always the first textbox, because you are changing the value of disabled attribute always on button1. 
You can use the onclick attribute for every input button, and adding into this for example this code:

```
var current_tr = $(this).parent();
var editable_input = current_tr.children(':first').prop('disabled', false);
```

So each input button becomes:

```
<td> <input type="button" name="test" value="Edit" onclick="var current_tr = $(this).parent(); current_tr.children(':first').prop('disabled', false);" /> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("table tr td input[type='button']").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```